# AWS installing mod_ssl on apache

Tags: ubuntu, ssl, amazon-web-services, certificate

I tried installing mod_ssl,I used this command `apt-get install mod_ssl` to install but I got an error saying `unable to locate package mod_ssl`.

After executing the above command, I got below output

```
Reading package list.. Done
Build dependency tree
Reading state information done..
E:unable to locate package mod_ssl
```

How do I resolve it ?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Run the command `dpkg -S mod_ssl.so`. Chances are that it will display something like:

```
apache2.2-common: /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_ssl.so
```

It means that `mod_ssl` is already installed on your system, as it does not come in a separate package, but it is bundled in `apache2.2-common`. Run

```
a2enmod ssl
```

to enable it, if it is not already enabled.

Comment: :Thank you,it worked.I'm trying to install SSL on my ec2,following this post http://www.akadia.com/services/ssh_test_certificate.html but struck.In step 5 ,when i type cp server.crt /usr/local/apache/conf/ssl.crt ,i get an error saying no such dir or file.How to resolve this ?

Comment: That guide isn't meant for Ubuntu. It is instructing you to copy the server certificate into a folder that does not exist on your machine. You may want to follow http://www.linode.com/wiki/index.php/Apache2_SSL_in_Ubuntu or https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/serverguide/httpd.html . Make sure to look carefully at what you specify in the configuration file for the SSLCertificateFile and SSLCertificateKeyFile directives, and copy the files into the right directories, with the right names.